# How to databind in the Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. I have an xaml file, that includes a label. Also, I have instance of a custom object called `tempObject`. It is of type `TempObject`.

I need to display values of `TempObject` on my UI.

`TempObject` has Name and Description as public string element.

I tried following code:

```
<Label Text="{Binding ElementName=tempObject , Path=Name}" TextColor="#0099DC" />
```

It throws exception.

Could you please help me how to bind an object to Labels in my xaml file.

Comment: What's the exception? try "{Binding Source=tempObject, Path=Name}" or "{Binding tempObject.Name}" turning on XAML compilation might give you an error that would help: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/

Comment: When I tried Source=... it is blank page. It look it does not bind.@RichardPike

Comment: You probably need to set the binding context and ensure your declaration of tempObject has a get. As @Prashant indicated in his answer the databinding basics is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

What is the `BindingContext` in your page? Using the `ElementName` is not correct in this scenario.

You can use the `{Binding tempObject.Name}` if `tempObject` object available in the context

You may want to read through the Databinding basics for Xamarin.Forms https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Comment: Where and how to set BindingContext ?

Comment: @erdemgc you may want to read through the XAML basics, the Xamarin.Forms XAML is quite different from the WPF's XAML https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/